# Create OLE object from Windows service

Tags: c#, matlab, service, com

I have Windows service that tries to create and use OLE object (namely - Matlab via automation) with this code:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("matlab.application");
var matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Everything works OK on my machine (Win7 x64, with single user), but on production server (Win 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1) I have problems. It works there if I start service as usual exe file (I have this possibility), but if I try to start it as service, it returns excepion:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {AC62BA4E-6ED9-4F33-9967-B260419E5EAD} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

I tried:

- start service under System/Administator/another user account
- check configuration with dcomcnfg utility (it helps actually, I had another error, but now all permissions for "matlab.automation" dcom object are granted)
- ater call of "Activator.CreateInstance" there is Matlab.exe process in memory, but it just hangs..

So - how can I use Matlab automation object from Windows service?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

Probably  it will help - production server is Amazon EC2 instance, so it has also Terminal Server. Maybe this could be a problem? Because I had problem with mutexes before, and it was resolved by creating global mutex..

**UPDATE 2**

Exception occurs always in 120 seconds (exactly), so it looks like OLE client doesn't see call of CoRegisterClassObjects, or probably any other call. In any case - delay between call of Activator.CreateInstance and exception is exactly 120 seconds.

Comment: What References are you using that are on `your working machine`, that are not on the `Target Machine`

Comment: Also which OLE Object are you trying to create..? Access, MS Word, Excel..? please show more relevant code.. also look at GAC to make sure that target machine has the correct version of the assembly GAC'd

Comment: @DJ KRAZE Hmm, honestly, I don't think that problem is there. There are references to System, System.Core, RabbitMQ.Client (it's presented on production server) and 4 custom assemblies (they are also on production server). First of all, there is NO reference to Matlab in any way. Secondly - it works when service starts as exe, but doesn't work when starts as service. So, problem should be somewhere in permissions/group policy settings/service settings, but.. where?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I wrote only 2 lines of code, and it's clear enough that it is Matlab object, isn't it? Also, it should not be in GAC - it's not .NET assembly, it's OLE object, it should not be .NET assembly (and as result - it can't be in GAC). Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, which code do you want to see? There are just 2 relevant lines of code, and both are provided..

Comment: When you start your service up (or in the thread you are doing work in) can you try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);` before doing anything? IIRC (and I'll look for a link when I have more time) the security policy for Windows Services is to run with a default context. This is probably also why it works as an exe.

Comment: @dash - I will try now..

Comment: @dash thanks :) BTW, I tried your code - it looks like it doesn't work, but I will try now to prepare separate service with as few lines of code as possible, and will let you know again..

Comment: @dash Now I'm sure that your code doesn't help :(